# Geodatabase: When adding a point feature layer from the geodatabase in ArcGIS Pro, the points show up but the symbology doesn't

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I have a geodatabase where I store my feature layers. Whenever I want to open a feature layer from this geodatabase the symbology I added previously isn't there.

[image]
[image]

**first picture**: How it should be

**Second picture**: How it looks when I open the feature layer from my GDB

The problem is that I now have to change the symbology again each time.

Anyone know why this is? And how to make the symbology change permanent?

Comment: I am using layerfiles currently. But it is not an optimal proces. You still have to use a layer file every time you open a feature layer from your geodatabase. It just doesn't save it

Comment: Then layer files (and project files) are your only options as [ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000015363) doesn't support [representations](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/what-are-representations-.htm) currently

Answer (score 4):

A featureclass and a layer file are two different things: A featureclass is just tabular data which can be stored in a geodatabase. It has no knowledge of how it should be symbolized. Therefore, every time you add a featureclass to the map, it will have some default symbology. A layer file on the other hand stores symbology, and has a *reference* to a featureclass

Want you can do is:

- Save the ArcGIS Pro project and use that. Symbology will be stored in the project

Or, if you want to use this one layer in another project:

- Save the layer as a layerfile: Right click on the layer in the TOC, select Sharing → Save as Layer File. Instead of adding the underlying featureclass, add this layer file
- Copy and paste the layer from one project to another (or from one map to another)
- Save the layer as a Layer Package: A layer package will contain a *copy* of the original data, and the symbology